# In my Laravel 8 Multi step form not submitting

Tags: laravel, forms, eloquent, laravel-8

Form not submit, eventually, it does not show any error, When I click on submit button nothing happens.

**Blade file**

```html
<form id="msform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('agent.emp.data.add') }}">

    @csrf

    <fieldset>

        <input type="text" name="empName" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />

        <input type="text" placeholder="Date Of Birth" name="empDob" onfocus="(this.type='date')"
            onblur="(this.type='text')" id="date" />

        <input type="email" name="empEmail" placeholder="Enter Your Email Id" />

        <input type="tel" name="empPhone" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number" />

        <input type="button" name="next" value="Next" />

    </fieldset>

    
    <fieldset>

        <input type="file" name="empPhoto" accept="image/*" onchange="empphoto(this);">

        <input type="button" name="previous" value="Previous" />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

    </fieldset>

</form>
```

**Web Route**

```php
Route::post('empdataform', [AgentController::class, 'AgentEmpDataAdd'])->middleware('guest')->name('agent.emp.data.add');
```

> Note: I add the AgentController In Route Top

**Agent Controller**

```php
class AgentController extends Controller
{
    public function AgentEmpDataAdd(Request $request){
        return $request->all();
    }
}
```

Please Help me in this mater.

Comment: Don't you see any message on console or network tab after submitting?

Comment: Hey, can you remove non important HTML (like the class attribute and container divs) from your code ? that would make your question more readable, I did submit an edit by the way https://ibb.co/DLY9H2F

Comment: @medilies Thanks For the Response, But it was solved, Issue happened for jQuery.